# Using blender to load 3d model

Tags: model, 3d, blender, fuse

I am trying to import fuse model to blender and from blender to unity. I dont know how to apply textures (if its needed). all tutorials seems to use diferent version of blender. So how do I apply textures or load them in blender[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A6sh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are UV mapped you can just apply a material in Unity and set a texture in the material, Standard material can be configured for most cases.

in blender

-> go to shading at top menu

-> add -> texture -> image texture in material graph node

-> file browse for your texture -> drag the hook from color into the 'Base Color' slot

[image]

export as fbx and include materials in export window

Comment: Ok so I tried skipping blender and just importing file into unity (mexamo said file is unity compatible) and.. well it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/jEVWlt2.png I do not know why his textures still don't load completely

Comment: create new material for each part and reassign them with a material/standard surface shader, mixamo does something weird with textures and culling/occlusion

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely new at this, do you perhaps have a link or more in depth explanation on what to do, since I really am confused at this point

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html then you can just drag and drop them onto your model

Comment: Ok so I did as suggested and the eyes and mouth seem to be in place, but the problem is that I lose the texture itself. I still need the texture that I am using for the character. If i try to reaply the old texture it goes back to looking freeky. WHat do I do?

Comment: the texture will be somewhere in unity, click on albedo on the ones mixamo imports and it will show you where the texture is in your folder

Comment: Yes i see it, but like I said if I put it on again it still looks bad

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just stupid. Thank you! works great!